# How to change network settings for a KVM on-the-fly?

Tags: linux, debian, qemu, kvm

Every time I add a new VM and try to attach a static ip, it won't work from the first attempt.

So I install a new VM with `virt-install`, then I add a static host to my virtual network interface (`virsh net-edit default`):

```
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>5582ba50-a089-4210-8163-cf79987bff8d</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:60:cc:1a'/>
  <ip address='192.168.100.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.100.100' end='192.168.100.254'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:db:f4:3b' name='machine1' ip='192.168.100.2'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:d5:6b:bb' name='machine2' ip='192.168.100.3'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I turn off the VM and do

```
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-start default
systemctl restart libvirtd
```

Then when the VM boots, it either gets an ip from the DHCP range, or it doesn't get an ip address at all. After multiple restarts, the VM gets the correct ip.
What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to modify network settings for a specific VM without hurting the others? I do "net-destroy", so all VMs get shut down during this process.

Answer (score 0):

According to my observations, this works ok:

After a host was added (virsh net-edit), the VM should be shut down by means of `virsh` (`virsh shutdown machine-name`)

Then
`virsh net-destroy default && virsh net-start default`

`systemctl restart libvirtd` is not required at all